# How to automatically close the panel after updating the user password in a React project?

Tags: reactjs, redux, passwords, logout

After updating the user password in the react project, I want the panel to be closed and transferred to the login page. With what method can I do this?

I'm using Redux.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] of any relevant code you are working with that you need help improving. Clarify what the specific issue or problem is.

Answer (score -1):

on password change do `navigate('/login')` using the useNavigate hook from [react-router-dom](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate)

Comment: I tried this, but after updating the password, I cannot log out of the panel. I want it to go to the login screen after the password is updated.

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    navigate('/login')
    axios
      .put(API_URL + `user/edit/` + editData.id, editData, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then((response) => {})
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }

Comment: you can call the navigate function in the `then((response) => {})`of the axios call, check if the request was successful then navigate if it was

Comment: It returns 200 on the axios side. The password is updated, but the session on the panel is not closed. Unable to transfer user to login page.

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios
      .put(API_URL + `user/edit/` + editData.id, editData, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        navigate('/login')
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }

Comment: i don't know what the panel you're referring to is, perhaps look up its documentation.

Comment: react core ui admin panel